# Plotting XAML images

Tags: wpf, xaml, 3d

Our product currently uses WPF to plot 3d images of parts which are created dynamically in code using objects descended from ModelVisualBase. So far, the parts have been very simple and created from cubes and cylinders.

We have now been asked to display more complex parts so want to use images supplied from the manufacturer. I have found that wavefront images (.obj) can be imported into Expression Blend or directly as XAML. I also found a previous question about extracting images from one viewport and importing into another [WPF: How to add 3D object from xaml file to my viewport3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580153/wpf-how-to-add-3d-object-from-xaml-file-to-my-viewport3d). However, this example doesn't show how to repeat the process and control where each part is positioned.

So, is it possible to have library images of individual parts in XAML and then plot them repeatedly in the correct position?

Comment: Could you explain more? The question isn't clear from "how to repeat the process" and on. What have you tried?

Comment: Huge time pressure means I haven't tried much yet. So far only got as far as importing an image from a graphics tool into XAML and displaying it on screen. What I'd like to get to is a set of images, one for each part. Then the ability to plot any of the parts in a given location using a 3d coordinate. The question I refer to shows how to get images out of a viewport but not how to position them.